# How can I zip with artifacts the entire laravel released folder?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, laravel-envoy

I'm struggling to figure it out this. I'm trying to create an artifact from whole project after deploy process ends and it drops the release folder but I'm missing something about this, I mean, I want to zip all the released folder. This is my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - unit_test
  script:
    - *init_ssh
    - envoy run deploy --on="staging" --commit="$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://app.steew-twebl.com

  # Do not run automatically.
  # Wait for a human to click on play.
#  when: manual

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - public/
      - resources/
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: on_success

  only:
    - master
```

the 'envoy run deploy' script run all the laravel project set up tasks , and on success I want zip the released folder. Instead separated paths, how can I get the root path for it?

Comment: Have you tried: artifacts:
    paths:
      - /var/www/project_name
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: on_success?